# C# - Как получить доступ к атрибутам экземпляра классов в других формах?

Tags: c#, winforms, классы

Дан файл .cs который содержит Класс:

```
public class ITWorkerDefaultClassObject
{
    public  string Name;
    public  string Surname;
    public  string Login;
    public  string Password;

    public  int TaskCounter;
}

public class SuperVisor : ITWorkerDefaultClassObject
{
    public  int AppliedCounter;
    public  int DeclinedCounter;
    public  int ActiveTaskCounter;


    public SuperVisor()
    {
        ActiveTaskCounter = 0;
        AppliedCounter = 0;
        DeclinedCounter = 0;
    }
}
```

Проблема в том, что я создал экземпляры классы в главной форме, однако когда я пытаюсь получить данные\записать данные в атрибуты экземпляра, то я не могу этого сделать. Появляется ошибка о том, что данного типа\переменной не существует в текущем контексте.

Я знаю что можно передавать значения между формами через изменение конструктора формы:

```
AdministratorForm AdminForm = new AdministratorForm(SuperVisor.ActiveTaskCounter)
```

Однако это не помогло мне, потому что у меня больше чем две формы и этот метод полностью привел меня в тупик, так как из второй формы мне также надо обработать и отправить данные в форму 3 и 4.

Есть ли какой-то общий метод вызова\обращение к атрибутам экземпляра класса для записи\вывода в любой другой форме кроме первой?

Comment: Прошу прощения! Первый раз пользуюсь сайтом, я думал я на английской ветке.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если нужен доступ из множества форм к одному и тому же экземпляру класса, то весь класс можно пометить как `static`:

```
public static class SuperVisor : ITWorkerDefaultClassObject
```

В таком случае к методам класса можно обратиться как `SuperVisor.AppliedCounter`

Однако, если возникает данная проблема это может говорить о непродуманной архитектуре программы.

Comment: Здравствуйте, MoHcTpUk! Попытка добавить метку static приводит к ошибке и невозможности объявлении переменных внутри класса. Я не понимаю почему это происходит. Если честно, хотелось бы понять вкратце какую роль играет метка static. Разве недостаточно того, что сам класс уже имеет установку доступа в виде public метки?

Comment: Если класс почемен как static, то и все его поля и методы тоже должны быть помечены как static. Вкратце - если класс статический, то для него создается один единственный экземпляр на всю программу. Для обычных же классов может быть сколько угодно экземпляров.

Comment: Большое спасибо за информацию, @MoHcTpUk!

Comment: Я нашел решение проблемы благодаря Вам! Путем экспериментов, я обнаружил, что часть методов можно сделать статическими, тем самым позволяя их вызывать в любом месте программы. Огромное Вам спасибо! Я помечу ваш комментарий как ответ на свой вопрос, спасибо!